# Variables/Userinput no being resolved

Tags: java

Ok so here it is:
I ask for the numbers picked
Then ask for the numbers that are drawn
Then when I goto so if they match up its telling me that **pickOne** can not be resolved but I'm using the users' input, what I have I done wrong?

I searched multiple things on sight none seemed to show the same problem. So I'm sorry if I'm not smart on finding the answer if it has been answered. I did search for about 30 min.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;


public class CheckNumber {  
    public static void main(String[] args){

     Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        int matchOne;
        int matchTwo;
        int matchThree;
        int matchFour;

        /*
         * 
         ********** THE NUMBERS CHOSEN BY USER **********
         *
        */

        System.out.println("First number picked: ");

        if (userInput.hasNextInt()){

            int pickOne = userInput.nextInt();

        }

        System.out.println("Second number picked: ");

        if (userInput.hasNextInt()){

            int pickTwo = userInput.nextInt();

        }

        System.out.println("Third number picked: ");

        if (userInput.hasNextInt()){
            int pickThree = userInput.nextInt();    
        }

        System.out.println("Fourth number picked: ");

        if (userInput.hasNextInt()){

            int pickFour = userInput.nextInt();

        }

        /*
         * 
         ********** THE WINNING NUMBERS DRAWN **********
         *      
        */

        System.out.println("First number drawn: ");

        if (userInput.hasNextInt()){
            int drawnOne = userInput.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("First number drawn: ");

        if (userInput.hasNextInt()){
            int drawnTwo = userInput.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("First number drawn: ");

        if (userInput.hasNextInt()){
            int drawnThree = userInput.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("First number drawn: ");

        if (userInput.hasNextInt()){
            int drawnFour = userInput.nextInt();
        }

        /*
         ********** MATCHING NUMBERS **********
        */
```

**Here is the problem:**

```
        if (pickOne == drawnOne){
            System.out.println(pickOne + " is a match!");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: by the way the scope of variable `pickOne` and `drawOne` is limited to the if condition. you should declare them inside main function as a local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables defined in a block are only accessible from within the block. In your program, the scope of your `pickedOne`, `pickedTwo`, ...., `drawOne`, `drawTwo`, .... variables are limited to the `if` blocks where you declared them. So, if you try to use them outside those `if` conditions, you will get error saying, `cannot find symbol`.

Declare the following variables inside `main()` function instead of inside `if` conditions.

```
int pickOne;
int pickTwo;
int pickThree;
int pickFour;

int drawnOne;
int drawnTwo;
int drawnThree;
int drawnFour;
```

I highly encourage you to read about [scope of variables in Java](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/).

Comment: Ok awesome sorry I thought i was good i haven't coded in a while and thanks for the link its already helped another problem i encountered. Have a great night and take it easy

Answer (score 0):

What's the input and the output. Give some examples. I don't see a good use of **if (userInput.hasNextInt())**

Do you mean like this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class CheckNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        int matchOne;
        int matchTwo;
        int matchThree;
        int matchFour;

        int pickOne;
        int pickTwo;
        int pickThree;
        int pickFour;

        int drawnOne;
        int drawnTwo;
        int drawnThree;
        int drawnFour;

        /*
         ********** THE NUMBERS CHOSEN BY USER **********
         */

        System.out.println("First number picked: ");
        pickOne = userInput.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Second number picked: ");
        pickTwo = userInput.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Third number picked: ");
        pickThree = userInput.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Fourth number picked: ");
        pickFour = userInput.nextInt();

        /*
         * 
         ********** THE WINNING NUMBERS DRAWN **********
         * 
         */

        System.out.println("First number drawn: ");
        drawnOne = userInput.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Second number drawn: ");
        drawnTwo = userInput.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Third number drawn: ");
        drawnThree = userInput.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Fourth number drawn: ");
        drawnFour = userInput.nextInt();

        /*
         ********** MATCHING NUMBERS **********
         */

        if (pickOne == drawnOne) {
            System.out.println(pickOne + " is a match!");
        }

    }

}
```